# How to push dynamic value in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, linechart

I have to push dynamic value in data

```
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [], label: 'prices are' },
  ];
```

From  my method I am pushing values as:

```
for(let e of x){
      
      this.lineChartData.push(e.raise)
     
    };
```

How can I push value in data[]?

Comment: You mean `lineChartData[0].data.push(e.raise)`?

Comment: If `e.raise` contains an object in the form of `{ data: [], label: string },`, it will be pushed to `lineChartData` as a whole. What is exactly the problem you are solving? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

you are having nested array/ so you need to run for loop twice

for eg

```
myArr = [{data:[]}]

for(let i of myArr){
  i.data.push('a');
}
```

I am passing string you can pass your object/array

using your example object

```
lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [], label: 'prices are' },
  ];

for(let i of lineChartData){
    i.data.push(yourObject)
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I push value in data[]?

Use

```
lineChartData[0].data.push(e.raise);
```